# LibGDX screen transition using stage

Tags: android, libgdx

I am very new to this so please make it easy for me to understand. I have created a game with three different screens and now that I have finished the game I wanted to add fade in and out transitions between the screens. I am trying to use the stage.addAction to perform these effects however it does not produce any effect. I am not using any stage or actors for my game so I am only adding the stage for the sole purpose of the fading out effect.

There is no error on my app, however, it does nothing when the stage.addAction is called.

Here is the parts of my code relating to the stage.

```
private Stage stage;

show() stage = new Stage();

render() stage.draw

onTouchUp() stage.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.fadeOut(1), Actions.run(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                game.setScreen(new gameScreen(game));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fade out method looks fine so it should be working. You should consider two following questions:

- do you remembered about calling **stage.act()** in render? If not the actions won't be proceed
- are you sure **onTuchUp()** in your case working fine? Try to add some System.out.println() into this method

Comment: thanks for answering!! it was the stage.act(), however there is no fade effect? if i change the length of the fadeout, it takes longer for the runnable to run (change screen) so it is working, but do you know why I cant see any fade?

Comment: How do you want to see fade when there are no actors? ;)

Comment: I just want the whole screen to fade away before starting the next screen, I havent used any actors as I am new to coding :P my game is complete but would it be possible to still have this effect? what would I have to do?

Comment: Nope - the stage is just kind of transparent surface that you are adding actors (images, labels, buttons...) onto. I'm not really sure how your game looks like and how it will behave but what I would try to do in your position would be adding a whole-screen size black (or what color you use to clear the screen) actor to the stage, make it transparent and then actually fade in when want to "fade out". If you will act() and draw() after rendering other things it should be ok in my opinion